# last and first value from group

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-performance

I have a task: get first, last, max, min from each group (by time) of data. My solution works but it is extremely slow because row count in table is about 50 million.

How can i improve performance of this query:

```
SELECT
   date_trunc('minute', t_ordered."timestamp"),
   MIN (t_ordered.price),
   MAX (t_ordered.price),
   FIRST (t_ordered.price),
   LAST (t_ordered.price)
FROM(
    SELECT t.price, t."timestamp"
    FROM trade t
    WHERE  t."timestamp" >= '2016-01-01' AND t."timestamp" < '2016-09-01'
    ORDER BY t."timestamp" ASC
) t_ordered
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

FIRST and LAST are aggregate functions [from postgresql wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate))

Timestamp column indexed.
explain (analyze, verbose):

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=13112830.84..33300949.59 rows=351556 width=14) (actual time=229538.092..468212.450 rows=351138 loops=1)
   Output: (date_trunc('minute'::text, t_ordered."timestamp")), min(t_ordered.price), max(t_ordered.price), first(t_ordered.price), last(t_ordered.price)
      Group Key: (date_trunc('minute'::text, t_ordered."timestamp"))
      ->  Sort  (cost=13112830.84..13211770.66 rows=39575930 width=14) (actual time=229515.281..242472.677 rows=38721704 loops=1)
         Output: (date_trunc('minute'::text, t_ordered."timestamp")), t_ordered.price
         Sort Key: (date_trunc('minute'::text, t_ordered."timestamp"))
         Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 932656kB
         ->  Subquery Scan on t_ordered  (cost=6848734.55..7442373.50 rows=39575930 width=14) (actual time=102166.368..155540.492 rows=38721704 loops=1)
             Output: date_trunc('minute'::text, t_ordered."timestamp"), t_ordered.price
             ->  Sort  (cost=6848734.55..6947674.38 rows=39575930 width=14) (actual time=102165.836..130971.804 rows=38721704 loops=1)
                Output: t.price, t."timestamp"
                Sort Key: t."timestamp"
                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 993480kB
                ->  Seq Scan on public.trade t  (cost=0.00..1178277.21 rows=39575930 width=14) (actual time=0.055..25726.038 rows=38721704 loops=1)
                      Output: t.price, t."timestamp"
                      Filter: ((t."timestamp" >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t."timestamp" < '2016-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 9666450
Planning time: 1.663 ms
Execution time: 468949.753 ms
```

Maybe it can be done by window functions? I have tried but i do not have enough knowledge to use them

Comment: What is the performance and row count of the inner query?

Comment: If you remove the `first()`, `last()` and `order by` in the subquery, how is the performance?

Comment: row count of the subquery query is about 6 million

Comment: i need order by in the subquery, without it whole query loose sense

Comment: Just wondering, is the timestamp column indexed?

Comment: `order by` in the subquery has influence on 
   `FIRST (t_ordered.price),
   LAST (t_ordered.price)`

i want first and last price ordered by timestamp

Comment: The seq scan on `trade` takes quite some time and because the `where` clause doesn't filter enough values an index on `timestamp` (horrible name for a column by the way) won't help much. Additionally sorting those 40 million rows can't be done in memory so that also adds a lot of time (nearly 2 minutes). And then the outer query is sorted _again_ which is _again_  is done on disk

Comment: I see the problem. How can it may be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a type and adequate aggregates will hopefully work better:

```
create type tp as (timestamp timestamp, price int);

create or replace function min_tp (tp, tp)
returns tp as $$
    select least($1, $2);
$$ language sql immutable;

create aggregate min (tp) (
    sfunc = min_tp,
    stype = tp
);
```

The `min` and `max` (not listed) aggregate functions will reduce the query to a single loop:

```
select
    date_trunc('minute', timestamp) as minute,
    min (price) as price_min,
    max (price) as price_max,
    (min ((timestamp, price)::tp)).price as first,
    (max ((timestamp, price)::tp)).price as last
from t
where timestamp >= '2016-01-01' and timestamp < '2016-09-01'
group by 1
order by 1
```

explain (analyze, verbose):

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=6954022.61..27159050.82 rows=287533 width=14) (actual time=129286.817..510119.582 rows=351138 loops=1)
   Output: (date_trunc('minute'::text, "timestamp")), min(price), max(price), (min(ROW("timestamp", price)::tp)).price, (max(ROW("timestamp", price)::tp)).price
   Group Key: (date_trunc('minute'::text, trade."timestamp"))
   ->  Sort  (cost=6954022.61..7053049.25 rows=39610655 width=14) (actual time=129232.165..156277.718 rows=38721704 loops=1)
      Output: (date_trunc('minute'::text, "timestamp")), price, "timestamp"
      Sort Key: (date_trunc('minute'::text, trade."timestamp"))
      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1296392kB
      ->  Seq Scan on public.trade  (cost=0.00..1278337.71 rows=39610655 width=14) (actual time=0.035..45335.947 rows=38721704 loops=1)
          Output: date_trunc('minute'::text, "timestamp"), price, "timestamp"
          Filter: ((trade."timestamp" >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (trade."timestamp" < '2016-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
          Rows Removed by Filter: 9708857
Planning time: 0.286 ms
Execution time: 510648.395 ms
```

Comment: Thanks it looks way better. How do make postgres do `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1296392kB` in memory?

Comment: @user2500146 Check the `work_mem` value in `postgresql.conf`. Test the index `create index minute on t (date_trunc('minute', timestamp))`